# Wordpress: Increasing text size of navigation menu

Tags: wordpress

Apologies - this is probably a really basic question but I've been trying different options for a while and nothing seems to work.

Just trying to increase the font size in the main Menu navigation.

```
    <div class="site-top-container clearfix">
                    <div class="site-logo-left-handler"></div><div class="site-menu-outer">
    <div class="site-menu-container brnhmbx-font-1 fw700 clearfix">
    <div class="site-nav2"><ul id="site-menu" class="menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-419 current_page_item menu-item-420"><a href="mainlink/" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-423"><a href="about/">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-432"><a href="menu/">Menu</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-426"><a href="find-our-vans/">Find our Vans</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-462"><a href="for-events/">Events</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-435"><a href="contact-us/">Contact Us</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-488"><a href="send-us-an-enquiry/">Send us an Enquiry</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-483"><a href="book-our-van/">Book our Van</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul></div> </div>
    </div><div class="top-extra-outer"><div class="top-extra"><div class="top-extra-inner clearfix"><div class="header-social brnhmbx-font-2"><a class="social-menu-item" href="LINK/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i><span>facebook</span></a><a class="social-menu-item" href="LINK" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i><span>twitter</span></a></div><div class="brnhmbx-top-search-button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div><div class="top-search" style="display: none;"><input class="top-search-input brnhmbx-font-1" type="text" value="Type keyword to search" name="s" id="s_top"> 
   </div></div></div></div>             </div>
```

I've tried

```
    .site-menu > li > a
    {
    font-size:38px !important;
    }
```

No luck.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the next one css code:

```
#site-menu > li > a
{
font-size:38px !important;
}
```

Comment: Your <ul id="site-menu" class="menu"> tag doesn't have a class "site-menu". Use the next one selector "#site-menu>li>a{font-size:38px !important;}" or ".menu>li>afont-size:38px !important;"